# Selenium CSS selector intepretation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this line

```
btns = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.css identifier')
```

and it gives a list of matched elements that look like this

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="session hash", element="element hash")>
```

what does the element hash mean and how can I find the html tag with it?

I understand selenium is used on multiple languages, but replies in python would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you meant by "find the html tag with it"? Do you mean accessing the list webelements or something else? Maybe add an example of what the output you're after should be.

Comment: because the selenium output is just as shown above, I want to see the full tag, for example using ```beautifulsoup```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see between parentheses as "session=" and "element=" are nothing more but IDs allocated at runtime. I don't think you should get too hung up on these, they are dynamic and will change every time you run your script.

As for accessing the tags, you can do something like (and note these are only some examples):

```
for btn in btns:
    print(btn.text)
    #or
    print(btn.tag_name)
    #or
    print(btn.get_property("innerHTML")) #or whatever property you might want accessing
```

Comment: so the hashes are meaningless as far as the html of the page is concerned?

Comment: That's right, think of them as selenium internal ids rather than html source.

Comment: By the way, you will see them irrespective of identification method, nothing specific to css selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the full html element in selenium like BeautifulSoup use `ele.get_attribute("outerHTML")`

First iterate list of elements and then use `get_attribute("outerHTML")`

```
btns =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.css identifier')
for btn in btns:
    print(btn.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```